# Windows Azure ETag for concurrency control - incorrect ETag format?

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

The following code has been written for a Windows Azure table storage service:

```
var context = GetTableServiceContext();
context.AttachTo(_tableName, entity, eTag);
context.UpdateObject(entity);
var response = context.SaveChangesWithRetries(saveChangesOptions);
```

My goal with this code is to throw a http status code of 412 (precondition failed) if the eTag does not match the entity in table storage.  This will be done to control concurrent updates.  I am experiencing some strange behavior when executing `SaveChangesWithRetries`.  Depending on the value of the `eTag` parameter being passed in, the following will occur:

`eTag` = W/”datetime’2010-08-17T23%3A43%3A26.1913755Z’” -> assuming this eTag does not match, then I will get a 412.  Perfect, that is what I am looking for.

`eTag` = W/"WrongETag" -> I will receive a DataServiceRequestException with a status code of 400.  The only error message is "invalid input"

`eTag` = "wrongETag" -> same as above

It seems that the azure table service demands an eTag of a more strict format than the HTTP standard requires.  All that should be required is a quoted string with an optional W/ prefix if it is weak.  Does anybody know the specific format required for the Azure table service?  Side-Note: Oddly enough, using the above ETags with Azure's Blob service behaves as expected.

Comment: Is there some reason you're messing around with ETag formatting instead of just passing back the exact same ETag that the service gave you?

Comment: I'm writing a test that ensures a particular custom exception is thrown when the ETag is invalid.

Comment: So in actual usage you're always going to send back an ETag you got from Azure Storage? If that's true, aren't you testing something you're never going to do? In any case, you should be treating their ETags as opaque and not be looking for their internal structure. The format is subject to change without notice at any time.

Comment: Point taken.  Thanks for the response!